# JDBC-ODBC issue - Resultset.getString() returning null when there is a value

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc

To begin, this is a problem that I am having on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008, but not on XP and Server 2003.

I am aware that between Windows Server 2003 and Windows Vista, Microsoft changed MDAC (we were shipping version 2.8) to WDAC 6.0, and I am assuming that my issue lies somewhere in that steaming pile of libraries.

I have an SQL statement: "SELECT TermStates.ActualCoeff FROM TermStates WHERE TermStates.AnalID = '000X' ORDER BY TermStates.indx ASC" which returns a single column of data, where it is assumed no values can be Null. These values are high precision, and most are quite small (ie. close to zero) and can also be negative.

The first set of data values looks like this:

-1.31182339008657
4.53959374804032
8.9828426279767
-0.07429423578308
1.90497874662919
-0.966443915857118
0.169642057606282
-0.825467091179711
-0.206287563886913
-1.00269723837058
-1.30688278976707
0.236262277634983
0
0
0
0.108773852550276
0
0
0 
**-0.0922931225677525**
0
0.217813798294512

And a second set looks like this:

-1.63590653334839
-0.959565335083171
9.91635261365054
-0.135820145149139
-3.2385711942924
-1.1562654250619
0.174470946581009
0
0
-1.13424407912293
0
1.0795237314308
0
0
0
0.132662710394659
0
0
0
**-0.0899603109525667**
0
0

There are many more columns of data, and they all exhibit the same issue. If the number being returned starts with "-0.0X", the results.getString() function will return null.

The basic code looks like this:

```
results = statement.executeQuery(sql);
if(results != null)
{
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = results.getMetaData();
    ArrayList rowList = new ArrayList();

    String colType = metaData.getColumnTypeName(1);
    Object obj = null;
    if(colType.equals("DOUBLE"))
    {
        obj = null;
        String fValue = results.getString(1);
        if(fValue != null && fValue.length() > 0)
        {
            obj = new Double(fValue);
        }
        else
        {
            obj = new Double(0.0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        obj = results.getString(1);
    }
    rowList.add(obj);
}
```

Has anyone ever seen behavior like this with the JDBC-ODBC bridge? I've been working in this environment for many years without any issues, but this one has me stumped. Is there anything about the bit alignment of "-0.0X" that might indicate a problem between 64 and 32 bit libraries, or? Any help you folks have would be appreciated.

Chris

Comment: Why don't you use `results.getDouble(1)`?

Comment: That actually throws an exception, so that's worse in some ways. This code is also used for other situations where just putting in a zero is not appropriate because null is a possible value.

Comment: @Chris: What exception does `getDouble` throw? Also, `ResultSet.wasNull()` is for cases where a primitive type column may be `null`. I created some wrapper methods for that myself... they call `getInt` or `getDouble` or whatever and then return `null` if `wasNull()` is `true` and the returned value otherwise.

Comment: @ColinD: I can certainly find a way around the error, but my problem is that I need the number that is actually in that field or the complex number crunching that occurs on this data will provide spurious data. Checking the exact error and the return value of wasNull().

Comment: @ColinD: The exception for trying to get a BigDecimal out is SQLException: No data found. result.wasNull() in the exception handler returns false. Same gor getDouble().

Comment: Why do you use the ODBC bridge? Why not use a "native" JDBC driver like jTDS or the Microsoft driver? And I would not recommend to use getString() on a column that is supposed to return a double.

Comment: @Chris: I think the "No data found" exception is when you try to read from the same column twice without advancing to a new result set row.

Comment: @ColinD: I'm starting to remember some of this from the initial implementation of the code many years ago. It's literally not been touched since at least 2002. I've gotten getObject(1) to work when it's the only call to retrieve the value. Trying getDouble(1) with a handler to check for null. That may allow this code to run correctly, as well as not screw up any of the other data builders that use the same function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You are probably correct. It's just strange that this functionality has been used literally many millions of times, but doesn't fail *ever* for the first 5 years it was deployed under XP and 2003 server.

Comment: If you are using Access (which you didn't mention) then you cannot use a "native" JDBC driver. So you are stuck with the ODBC bridge

Comment: I've got it working, simply by replacing the initial getString(1) with getDouble(1), and handling the exception when there is a null value. I don't know why I never tried that initially, but we were in crisis mode and my boss just decided to block Win7 and 2008 installation rather than spend time fixing the issue then. I guess I only tried getDouble(1) in an else case when getString(1) had already failed, and that caused the other problem, which is that you can't read the same value twice. Oh well, it's fixed. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `results.getDouble(1)`!

Comment: getDouble(1) will throw an error in this case. I have also tried getBigDecimal and a number of other possible work-arounds. It appears that the Java code is simply not able to pull any value out of the DB for the given row.

Comment: if getDouble(1) throws an error you are either not showing us everything or the ODBC bridge is seriously broken, as getDouble(1) is the **only** reliable way to obtain a double value from a ResultSet

Comment: That is everything. This code is running on many hundreds of deployments, parsing numbers many thousands of times on each installation. It wasn't until Vista/7/2008 that problems started happening.

Comment: @a_hores_with_no_name: Is it your experience with JDBC-ODBC bridge running on an access database that you can't query for the same result twice? I've seen some chatter on the Google, and remember that there was a problem like that about 8 years ago when I wrote this code initially. I just replaced getString(1) with getObject(1), and was able to toString() the values that were not working before.

Comment: From the Javadocs of ResultSet: *"For maximum portability, result set columns within each row should be read in left-to-right order, and each column should be read only once"*

Comment: @Chris: It seems from what I can tell that the JDBC-ODBC driver does not allow you to try to read from the same column of the same row twice. I'm not sure if that's the case for other drivers because I don't think I've ever tried to read from a column twice like that.

Comment: @ColinD: I have some notes in other parts of this code that say not to do it, but it's been forever since I had to write an DB code that I had just forgotten that rule. Lesson learned: read comments in entire file before trying stupid things.